# "Studies have shown..." vs "Studies have showed..."

Tags: past-tense, past-participles

My teacher corrected one of my writing assignments saying that 'have showed' is incorrect and that 'have shown' is the correct conjugation. But when I look [online](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/432202/we-have-showed-that-we-have-shown-that-or-we-showed-that), I see that my version is more correct given the context. Please guide me.

The context is trying to prove some opinion.

Comment: where do you see that your link says that "have showed" is more correct? Every answer and comment I see says "have shown" is more used and better sounding, and I would agree, even if it is not technically incorrect.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/432202/we-have-showed-that-we-have-shown-that-or-we-showed-that

Comment: Sorry, isn't that the same link you had already shown?

Comment: yes, it is. Doesn't it prove me correct?

Comment: It doesn't. You can either say "we have shown" or "we showed". Note the lack of "have". Saying "we have showed" is incorrect.

Comment: However, isn't *has/have showed* fairly common with the verb *show up*, especially with *show (someone) up*?

Comment: @DjinTonic As regards the verb "to show" - "showed" is the past tense, and "shown" the past participle.  With "show-up" a less formal verb, I would make the same distinction - saying "they have shown-up at last", or "they have been shown-up by their opponents", and I think most British speakers would agree. Though that may not be the case in the US. Perhaps one of our American colleagues might care to comment.

Comment: @WS2 As a speaker of AmE, I, too, would use "were shown up by ..."; however, peeking at Googe Books, I saw "showed" was common (used in narration also and not only dialog).

Answer (score 1):

The past participle of **show** is **shown**. The only correct answer is **have shown.**

You could say **showed** if you use the past tense: For example:

> We **showed** the house to 50 people.

But, you would only say:

> We **have shown** the house to 50 people.

Answer (score 0):

In British English, the only correct past participle of show is "shown".

In some older use, "showed" was used in forming the present perfect.  This is becoming rare in modern writing.

Learners should always use "shown" for the participle and "showed" for the past tense, but be aware that you may still see examples like:

> Faltering stock prices on Wall Street recently have showed the nation's nervousness over the US economy. ([source](https://news.google.com/newspapers?nid=1914&dat=20010827&id=ewFHAAAAIBAJ&sjid=v_MMAAAAIBAJ&pg=3114,4236903))